# Insights in AGOL - "We couldn't display all features" error

Tags: arcgis-online, insights-for-arcgis

I have a file geodatabase with a single feature class (polygon) which I have zipped and uploaded to my organisation's AGOL account and created a hosted feature layer.

There are just 11 polygons in my feature class.

I can view the data in a web map.

I can view the data in ArcMap.

I have tried adding it to Insights but it won't display all polygons when I add it to a map in Insights.  Some polygons will only display if I zoom in really close.  Some polygons won't display at all.  The 11 polygons encompass all the water areas around the UK, so they aren't small polygons.

If I open the dataset as a table in Insights, I can see all the records.

The same dataset was working a few weeks ago when I last used it in Insights.  The dataset has not been edited since.

The error I get:

[image]

If I click for more information, it just tells me how many features are being displayed.

The data is in wgs84.

Things I have tried.

1. Chrome (v66) and Internet Explorer 11.
2. Cleared cookies & cache.
3. In ArcMap, checked for geometry errors - there are none.
4. Saved the feature class to a new fgdb and added it to AGOL.  Same error.
5. Exported the feature class to a shp file, zipped this and added it to AGOL.  Same error.
6. Deleted the .prj file for the shp file and run the "Define Projection" tool in ArcMap and set it to wgs84.  Same error.
7. Re-projected the dataset to Web Mercator. Same error.
8. Checked the extent of the dataset.  This is correct.  As shown by the automatic thumbnail created in AGOL. I have double checked this by zooming to extent in ArcMap and AGOL.

[image]

9. Re-created the dataset from scratch.  Same error.
10. In the settings tab for the hosted feature layer in AGOL, I've optimised the layer drawing.  Same error.
11. Published as a service straight from ArcMap.  Same error.
12. Generalised the polygons in ArcMap and then repaired geometry to fix any self intersections caused by this process.  Have tried a 10m, 30m and a 100m generalisation.  At 100m, the vertices on the most complex polygon reduced from 50,000 to 19,000. However, there is no correlation between the polygons with the highest number of vertices and the polygons not displaying. i.e. The polygons with the fewest vertices (1233 pre generalisation, 469 post generalisation) is one of the ones not displaying.

I am at a total loss for what to do next.  Any ideas?

Is this just a glitch with Insights?  It's just confusing as the same dataset was working a few weeks ago.

Comment: @BERA i've now tried publishing straight from ArcMap.  Same error.  Have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: You could try ESRI support, maybe it is a bug. Or try simplifying the polygons, with Integrate or some other tool.-

Comment: Best guess is the number of vertices. Its following the coast line. try generalizing it a little bit (10m, 30m, etc) and using that. (remember, make a back up copy of your data, generalize modifies the input data)

Comment: @KHibma I have tried generalising the polygons but I am still seeing the same behaviour.  I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: When you publish from Arc have you tried increasing the number of features visible? I think it defaults to 1000. Yes I know you only have 11, you have tried everything I would have tried except that. I think the option is under "Parameters" in the publishing window.

Comment: How about repair geometry?  
If you open console in browser (F12) any errors being reported there?
If you can upload a layer package, happy to test from an ArcGIS Enterprise Insights version.  I would suggest contacting Esri UK - their support will be able to figure this out pretty quick

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Simon ESRI UK have replicated the behavior and ESRI inc have now confirmed it is a bug introduced in the latest update where an unknown vertex limit was inadvertently introduced.  Interestingly, the bug only exists in Insights on AGOL and not on Enterprise.